# Как сделать около вертикального блока, блоки переходящие на новую строку flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно сделать что-то типо такого плана. У меня после добавления верхнего правого блока, не переносится на следующую строку. А если использую flex-wrap: wrap переносится верхний блок под вертикальный. При этом, если удалить один блок,чтоб ничего не съехало. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  height: 100%;
}

.column-left {
  height: 66.5%;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
}

.column-right {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-wrap{
  padding: 1rem;
}

.column-left .item-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.column-right .item-wrap {
  flex-basis: 28%;
}

.column-right .item-wrap:first-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column-left column">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right column">
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrap">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```